# nested array inserting in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

I am using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) where I have a mongodb document where something inserted with the following code:

```
Poll_Coll.insert({question:quest,option1:[{pd:op1,ids:[]}],
        option2:[{pd:op2,ids:[]}],
        option3:[{pd:op3,ids:[]}],
        option4:[{pd:op4,ids:[]}]});
```

I want to update multiple ids in the `option1.ids` array, which I tried to do like this:

```
Polls_Coll.update({_id:"xxxx","option1.pd":"xxx"},{$push:{"option1.$.ids":6}});
Polls_Coll.update({_id:"xxxxx","option1.pd":"xxx"},{$push:{"option1.$.ids":{id:"ya"}}});
```

option1.pd is working perfectly. I tried both the above commands and am getting the error

> Error: MinimongoError: can't append to array using string field name [$] [409]

How do I insert into that ids field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the minimongo implementation being used by meteor as it currently does not support the positional $ operator.

From the following data sample the operations are working in the mongo shell

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52eb0a6542b2498fd49f4f28"),
    "question" : "quest",
    "option1" : [
            {
                    "pd" : "op1",
                    "ids" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "pd" : "op7",
                    "ids" : [ ] 
            }
    ],
    "option2" : [
            {
                    "pd" : "op2",
                    "ids" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "option3" : [
            {
                    "pd" : "op3",
                    "ids" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "option4" : [
            {
                    "pd" : "op4",
                    "ids" : [ ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Applying the following statement will push values onto the matching element's 'ids' array.

```
db.poll.update({"option1.pd": "op1"},{$push: { "option1.$.ids": 6 }})
```

Basically the same code will work server side as well.

It would seem the solution would be to wrap this update in a function call that can be invoked from the client and execute the code on the server.

Here are some links confirming the issue:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/153

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/minimongo/NOTES

Comment: This is how i'm inserting into the collection 'Polls_Coll.insert({question: quest,
     option1:[{pd:op1,ids:[]}],
     option2:[{pd:op2,ids:[]}],
     option3:[{pd:op3,ids:[]}],
     option4:[{pd:op4,ids:[]}]
     });'         and this is how i tried to update in the code       Polls_Coll.update({_id:this._id},{$push:{'option1.$.ids':'hooya'}}); i tried this in browser console this too not working     Polls_Coll.update({_id:"soeg9ezkMwKFmdPkT","option1.pd": "android"},{$push: { "option1.$.ids": 6 }})  i declared this collection at the top of the js file and published from the server side

Comment: and subscribed at client side. now i tried this in console Polls_Coll.update({_id:"soeg9ezkMwKFmdPkT","option1.pd": "android"},{$push: { "option1.$.ids": 6 }}) now it is showing error Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403] although i gave id. Thanks for the help

Comment: And yes that will be the issue. Updated notes on answer and your question to clarify this is a Meteor problem with minimongo. You won't be able to use the transparent "update" methods for this data and need to roll up a more traditional RPC call.

Comment: Hey Neil i appreciate your help and i am new to this stackoverflow. Once i get those 15 reputation points i'll definitely up vote your answer. Sorry for the delay